# Changing date format in a file with multiple records and columns

Tags: python

I am fairly new to awk, and I am having a file with four columns, separated by a space and I would like to change the date format of the 2nd and third column. I have shared a sample of the record below

```
349287741 20140123 20140329 7
```

I would like to change the date from %Y%m%d to %Y-%m-%d without affecting the record positions.

Comment: what did you try? and is `*` in original file or not? something like this: `349287741 20140123 20140329 7`  ? Try awk function gsub() or substr() function, you should do it by yourself. You can refer here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk '{ "date -d "$2" +%Y-%m-%d"|getline $2; "date -d "$3" +%Y-%m-%d"|getline $3;}1' yourfile
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to run this, but the date format was not changed, and I see it gives std output on the terminal how can I output this to a new file once the change of date has been done to my existing file

Comment: @user3354635, Like this: `awk '{ ...}' yourfile > newfile`

Comment: the date format conversion is not working I had done that "awk '{ ...}' yourfile > newfile" but the output is the same

Comment: @user3354635, what is the output of `date -d20140123 +%Y-%m-%d` command in terminal.

Comment: the output is  date -d20140123 +%Y-%m-%d
2014-01-23

Comment: For this, awk '{$2=gensub(/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/,"\\1-\\2-\\3","g",$2);$3=gensub(/([0-9‌​]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/,"\\1-\\2-\\3","g",$3)}1' it has not worked error function gensub never defined

Comment: Try this : `echo "349287741 2014-01-23 2014-03-29 7" | awk '{ "date -d "$2" '+%Y-%m-%d'"|getline $2; "date -d "$3" '+%Y-%m-%d'"|getline $3;}1'` and what is the output you are getting?

Comment: the output I am getting is this 

/bin/sh: 1: +%Y-%m-%d: not found
349287741 2014-01-23 2014-03-29 7

Comment: I was able to do this using python. Thank you so much for your assistance